# Setting a Qml Context Property in the Qt5.7 QtQuick2 application template

Tags: qt, qml

My goal is to populate a combo box with serial ports available on the (Windows) machine. I created a wrapper for QSerialPortInfo that I would like to publish as QML root context property. I used the QtQuick2 application template as starting point.

```
#include <QList>
#include <QObject>

class QuickSerialPortInformer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QString> portselectionmodel READ portselectionmodel CONST)

public:
    static const QuickSerialPortInformer *getInstance();

    QList<QString> portselectionmodel() const;

protected:
    QuickSerialPortInformer();

private:
    static const QuickSerialPortInformer *Instance;
};

#endif // QUICKSERIALPORTINFORMER_H
```

I register the object like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    /* here */ engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("serialPortInformer", QuickSerialPortInformer::getInstance());
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

The `QList<QString>` returned by the property shall serve as model for the combobox. My guess is that `QList<QString>` is converted to a JavaScript `array` of strings and then converted back to whatever the C++ part of the `ComboBox`'s model property needs. After all, the property accepts an array of strings defined in JavaScript. However, it seems that when assigning the property of the `QuickSerialPortInformer` to the `model` of the `ComboBox` no such marshalling is done. As pointed out in the comments, only some C++-types may be used as models for QtQuick views. One of them is `QStringList`, which I am using now.

```
ComboBox {
    id: portSelector
    model: serialPortInformer.portselectionmodel
}
```

My problem is that `SerialPortInformer` is unknown in the qml context. I suspect that the context I am using to register the object is not visible to the script I am executing with `engine.load()`. I tried to reverse the order of `load()` and `setContextProperty()` to no avail. What am I missing?

After renaming `SerialPortInformer` to `serialPortInformer` as suggested in the comments and documentation another problem arises. `serialPortInformer` is a `boolean` of value `true` in QML instead of the expected object.

I was able to solve the "boolean"-mystery to the extent that I have been able to make my use case work. The answer is that my `SerialPortInformer::getInstance()` was returning a pointer to `const`. As soon as I removed the `const`-qualifier `serialPortInformer` was of type object and exposed the desired attribute. The only reason I can think of why this compiled in the first place is that the `const QVariant &` overload of the method was called instead, using a non-`explicit` constructor. So my note-to-self is: *Never register pointers to constant `QObject`s in a QML context*

Comment: What happens if you use a lowercase name: `serialPortInformer`?

Comment: I had it like this before and just retried it. The problem is still there. `serialPortInformer` is not showing up in the qml debug window. I would expect it to be on the same level as `mainWindow`

Comment: I think you should use a lowercase name regardless, as http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute says it has to be lowercase. You could also use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType to register the object. That way you could still use the uppercase syntax and treat it as a singleton.

Comment: Is `SerialPortInformer` `undefined` when you print it out? What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: The item itself is visible the problem that your `ComboBox` cannot dispatch values. Try to replace `QList<QString>` with `QStringList`. See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) page for more info. Especially this note: `A C++ model class can be defined as a QStringList, a QObjectList or a QAbstractItemModel`. There is no `QList<QString>` here.

Comment: Also `portselectionmodel` should be declared as NOTIFYable property

Comment: console.debug(serialPortInformer) prints "true" to the console. Since there is no exception I think the object is actually there. I will go with folibis comment from here and use a different collection class, Although [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) says that `QList<QString>` and `QStringList` should both work.

Comment: I understood that the notifyable should only be present if the property is settable. Since I wanted the property to be readonly I thought that notifyable made no sense. Am I wrong?

Comment: I just did `console.debug(typeof serialPortInformer)` and it evaulated to 'boolean'. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: your value could be changed internally so NOTIFY is recommended. As for me I get warning message `Expression depends on non-NOTIFYable properties`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131809/discussion-between-folibis-and-everclear).

Comment: @everclear if the contents of the property does not change, use `CONSTANT` instead of `NOTIFY`

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to read the `QStringList`, just make `QStringList`  as the return type of a Q_INVOKABLE method. Also, I don't see you creating an object of `QuickSerialPortInformer` which you might be creating in your original code. To sum up your code should something like this,

```
#include <QList>
#include <QObject>

class QuickSerialPortInformer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList portselectionmodel();
    ....
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    QuickSerialPortInformer portInformer;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine; 
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("serialPortInformer",&portInformer);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, implement your `Q_PROPERTY` as follows ([see documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)):

```
Q_PROPERTY(QStringList portSelectionModel READ portSelectionModel WRITE setPortSelectionModel NOTIFY portSelectionModelChanged)
```

Not sure why your singleton is not working, but try implementing it like this:

```
public:
static QuickSerialPortInformer& Instance()
{
    static QuickSerialPortInformer instance; 
    return instance;
}
~QuickSerialPortInformer()=default;

private:
QuickSerialPortInformer()=default;
QuickSerialPortInformer(QuickSerialPortInformer const&)=delete;
void operator = (QuickSerialPortInformer const&)=delete;
```

On your main.cpp:

```
QQmlContext* quickSerialPortInformerCtx = engine.rootContext();
quickSerialPortInformerCtx->setContextProperty("quickserialportinformer", &QuickSerialPortInformer::Instance());
```

On your qml:

```
ComboBox {
    model: quickserialportinformer.portSelectionModel
}
```

It should work, I've used this implementation before.